# Tracking Multiple Youtube Videos with Youtube Api and Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, youtube-api, event-tracking

So I've successfully setup Google Analytics tracking for one video displayed using the Youtube Api. However, when I have more than one video on the same page the event tracking stops working.

This is my code:

```
<div id="player"></div>
<div id="player2"></div>
<div id="player3"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player;
    var player2;
    var player3;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            playerVars: {
                modestbranding: true,
                theme: 'light',
                rel: 0,
                wmode: "opaque",
                autoplay: '0'
            },
            height: '480',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'p01Sd5OzglI',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
        player2 = new YT.Player('player2', {
            playerVars: {
                modestbranding: true,
                theme: 'light',
                rel: 0,
                wmode: "opaque",
                autoplay: '0'
            },
            height: '480',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'qLFQUdmAkcQ',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
        player3 = new YT.Player('player3', {
            playerVars: {
                modestbranding: true,
                theme: 'light',
                rel: 0,
                wmode: "opaque",
                autoplay: '0'
            },
            height: '480',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'HP3vWQ_WRu8',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        /// event.target.playVideo(); 
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play',
            player.getVideoUrl()]);
        }
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Paused',
            player.getVideoUrl()]);
        }
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Watch to End',
            player.getVideoUrl()]);
        }
    }
    // ]]>
</script>
```

Can anyone figure this out?

Comment: I'm trying to narrow down the problem: 
Did you have any error in the console? 
Does one of the events get sent or none of them do? If none of them do - will sending an event outside of any function work?

Comment: This Will Help You https://github.com/lunametrics/youtube-google-analytics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function onPlayerStateChange references the first player directly.

```
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play',
            **player**.getVideoUrl()]);
        }
        // -- snip --
    }
```

So ALL the events are getting attributed to **player**, and NONE to **player2** or **player3**.

I think that instead of:

```
player.getVideoUrl()
```

you want to use:

```
event.target.getVideoUrl()
```

FYI, I find that for debugging GA code like this, it is very helpful to use the [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en)

Comment: Mark, could you take a look at my question and see if you know anything - I don't use `player.getVideoUrl` in it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23634106/how-can-i-track-two-videos-on-one-page-using-google-analytics-and-youtube-api

Comment: I have added this script in header. Only one video is present in this page but when scroll down more videos added using Ajax. how to trigger the youtube event for Ajax loaded videos? Please can you help me. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36497753/track-youtube-video-play-pause-end-with-google-analytics-events-via-ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36497753/track-youtube-video-play-pause-end-with-google-analytics-events-via-ajax) [@mark-hansen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1011062/mark-hansen)