# How can I track two videos on one page using Google Analytics and YouTube API?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-analytics, youtube-api, analytics

I've got a video on our website that I'm tracking the views of using Google Analytics. This is the code:

```
<!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

<script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var utm_source='<?php echo $utm_source ?>';
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '360',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
          frameborder: '0',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      //    Uncomment the event to have video start automatically.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        // event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                if (utm_source == 'zilch') {
                    ga('send', 'event', 'YouTube', 'Started', 'Promo from Main Page');
                }
                else if (utm_source == 'CAMPAIGN') {
                    ga('send', 'event', 'YouTube', 'Started', 'Promo from Main Page via CAMPAIGN');
                }
                else {
                    ga('send', 'event', 'YouTube', 'Started', 'Promo from Main Page');
                }
            }
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                if (utm_source == 'zilch') {
                    ga('send', 'event', 'YouTube', 'Finished', 'Promo from Main Page');
                }
                else if (utm_source == 'CAMPAIGN') {
                    ga('send', 'event', 'YouTube', 'Finished', 'Promo from Main Page via CAMPAIGN');
                }
                else {
                    ga('send', 'event', 'YouTube', 'Finished', 'Promo from Main Page');
                }
        }
      }
    </script>
```

If I copy and paste this code, and change the video ID it overwrites the original. If I copy and paste this code, and leave the video ID instead of showing two it just shows the original.

How can I work this so I have more then one video being tracked on the page? I'm thinking it has to do with the `<div id='player'></div>` but am not seeing how to change the target div.

Answer (score 1):

How I ended up working around this is using Nevo Lightbox. I then created a thumbnail for each video and linked it somewhat like so:

```
<a href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoID' data-lightbox-gallery='playlist' title='Video description' onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Video', 'Play', 'Demo on videos');">
```

Changing the VideoID and Video Description. There's probably a more elegant solution, but its getting the job done.